# Hibernate: CascadeType.ALL should try creating the object if it doesn't already exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two classes A and B such that

```
class A{

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    B b;

    // other stuff
}
```

In class B

```
class B{

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    // other stuff
}
```

Whenever a new object of A is created I want to create the object B if it doesn't already exist. However if it already exists then I don't want to create it. In this case I just want the reference in the A table of the already existing B object. Right now i get this exception when I try to do so

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This seems a standard task but I can't seem to find any solutions on stackoverflow etc. Can someone please help. Thanks !!

**Edit:** For doing the save I use Sring JPA repositories. I have repository interfaces for both A and B which ultimately extend `CrudReposioty` and use its save function. Below is the function from the `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`

```
/**
 * Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the
 * entity instance completely.
 * 
 * @param entity
 * @return the saved entity
 */
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

Comment: add the method that performs the save / update and causes the excetpion

Comment: can you make the Id in B a generated value?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski The id will be supplied so generated won't help. I guess this has more to do with Spring Data JPA then hibernate

Comment: how do you create A and B when saving them? its probably relevant

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the id of object B before inserting object A to the database. In this case, if B does not exist, B will be inserted into the database.

Comment: I do set the id and the case that you mentioned works fine. Its that when B exists in the db it throws the exception

Comment: What is the exception?